# Can't edit text in textarea element

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I am writing a script to automate some unnecessary teaching feedback.

I am using selenium/python to scrape data (student names & classes etc) and input the feedback. Everything works fine apart from inputting the feedback itself into the textarea element. Selenium gives me an ElementNotInteractable exception when using click() or send_keys().

I then tried using JS commands, eg:

```
comment = 'Thanks for coming to the lesson. Well done today!'
self.driver.execute_script(f'document.querySelector("#teacherCommentContent").innerText = "{comment}";')
```

I also tried editing in the chrome console using:

```
document.getElementById(teacherCommentContent).innerHTML = "message"
document.getElementById(teacherCommentContent).textContent = "message"
document.getElementById(teacherCommentContent).value = "message"
$(#teacherCommentContent).val("message")
```

None have been successful at updating the text in the textarea on screen, and as such I can't submit the feedback. Of course, I can manually enter the feedback, but that defeats the point.

[See picture of website and HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px5gh.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that website is behind a login, so I cannot test it. However, there are a few problems with your code:

- You are not waiting for the elements to fully load
- Did you check, is that textarea in an iframe, or shadowroot element?
- You can send keys (text) with Selenium

To wait for the element to load properly before trying to interact with it, you can use the following locator:

```
textarea_element = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'teacherCommentContent')))
```

To input some text in it, you can do (after you waited for the element to load, like above):

```
textarea_element.send_keys('An amazing teacher!')
```

You also need the following imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Lastly, Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Again, I cannot test this. You mentioned you are using selenium/python, so this would be a possible solution.

Comment: He mentions that he tried in chrome console (where element is loaded and iframe is in context) so none of these really apply...

Answer (score 0):

For textarea you want to set innerText (not value). But for PWAs that often won't be enough, you also must dispatch a change event to the textarea. You will find a way to do that if you google it.

Comment: I know basic js and jQuery, but am far from an expert. I have tried dispatching an event to the textarea, but no changes are implemented on screen, and I'm still unable to submit the feedback. I noticed that there is no "onchange" attribute for the textarea element, is this the issue? Could you provide more advice on what to do please?

Comment: Don't worry, think I found the solution. Will update later

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved once I realised the website designer had named two different textareas using the same html id. I could then select then second textarea and insert text directly into this.

```
script = f'''
                    var bothTextAreas = document.querySelectorAll("#teacherCommentContent");
                    bothTextAreas[1].innerText = "{comment}";
                            '''
self.driver.execute_script(script)
```